# Rendering Textures using VBOs

Tags: opengl, jogl

I am new bid to OpenGL. I am trying to understand a texture data mapped using Vertex Buffer Objects. I am not getting tutorials anywhere. Please suggest me any such tutorials or give the code describing the procedure.

Anand

Answer (score 0):

Try http://open.gl/textures. This question is not really suitable for SO though.

Comment: Actually starts tutorials with OpenGL 3.2. But I want to work with OpenGl 2.1 because my graphics card won't support OpenGL 3. Will you please explain me about how to proceed further with this.